# "Took an hour more" or "Took an hour longer"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Example:

> Mr. Sour Cream took 30 seconds **more/longer** than Ms. Onion to complete the race.

Should it be 'more' or 'longer'?

Answer (score 1):

Both are used and both are correct in  a range of contexts.

A reasonable way to check this kind of usage question is to use google or bing and search for "30 seconds longer" and "30 seconds more"  - see how frequent each expression is and are they being used in similar contexts.

---

You also win the prize for "most creative use foodstuffs in creating an example sentence"!

Comment: Thanks! It felt like "more" is more apt in my context (Onion the winner had an average speed of ____ and the loser took ___ seconds more than the winner.)..........and yay for the prize hahaa!